# Flutter - Running unit tests on Windows

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to run some unit tests I wrote from my command-line. It's now where I figure out that Flutter does not yet support running them on Windows. I saw some issues filed on GitHub about the problem. However, it has been a couple of months ago already. Has anything changed since then?

Or do I have any other way of running my unit tests? Developing without them seems to be a bit tedious to be honest...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update, 12 December 2017: This is now supported!

---

This is unfortunately currently not supported; tracking bug is https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8516.

If this is important to you, please up-vote it by clicking ["thumbs up"](https://flutter.io/support/) on the top comment in bug 8516.